# raspberry pi separate server broadcast audio stream

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, streaming

Ulitmately, I'm looking to use my Raspberry Pi as a mobile audio recorder/uploader, which streams the audio to a server. Then, the server will multicast the audio to listeners. The application is a live audio blog as I travel.

If I understand mulitcasting, multicasting from the pi would be unfeasible because each user would require the pi to handle serving a new audio stream.

So it seems that I'd need a separate server, probably amazon AWS or something similar, which receives an audio stream from my pi, then serves it to the user.

I think Icecast is what I'd want for the server to deliver the stream to users. But what is a good setup for the pi -> server -> icecast? Ideally I'd want to keep lag low, but I'll sacrifice low lag for an easy solution. I'd also like for the pi -> server stream to auto-downgrade in the case of low bandwidth, but I know that might be asking too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A program that actually creates an audio stream (from PI to Icecast server in your example setup) to Icecast server is called "source client". They all have different capabilities, it's up to you to choose the right one. You can get actual list of source clients here
http://icecast.org/apps/

I recommend `liquidsoap` as the most powerful tool, or you can use `ezstream`, cause it does not re-encode your music files and saves your CPU which is important on Raspberry Pi.